# Notes as reminders

Tags: notes.app, reminders

Is there a way with Apple Notes to set a time to be reminded of a note, as in Google Keep? Or must I set a reminder separately which reminds me to check the note?

Comment: Hi Luke, can you clarify whether you're referring to Apple Notes generally, or whether you're specifically asking about macOS or iOS?

Comment: At the time I was using my iPhone but generally I sync and use notes across iOS and macOS.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Notes within macOS you can trigger a reminder fairly easily. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Within Notes on macOS, ensure you have a note selected
2. In the toolbar, click on the Share icon and select the Reminders option (alternatively you can go to File > Share > Reminders)
3. This brings up a Reminders popup pre-populated with the name of your selected note
4. Now click on the *Info* icon at top right of the popup to set how you want to be reminded (see screenshot below)

[image]

The above screenshot shows the popup that appears when I created a dummy note called Luke's Question and then opted to *share* it to Reminders. By clicking on the blue *info* icon I get the options to remind me on a day, etc.

5. Click on the <kbd>Add</kbd> button at bottom right to add it to your Reminders

Now at the appointed time (or location) you'll get a reminder about the note. And, if you originally created the note as part of your iCloud notes, then this will get synced to your other devices as well.